# Why can't Hangfire find the executable it is running from?

Tags: .net-7.0, hangfire, self-contained

I have a very strange problem. I have a self-contained .NET 7 app. The executable is named `MyCompany.GVA.Api.exe`  . After running it, I executed the following SQL Code.

```
select * from HangFire.State s inner join HangFire.Job J on J.Id = s.JobId
where Reason like '%Could not resolve%' order by s.CreatedAt asc
```

This is the output:

| Id | JobId | Name | Reason | CreatedAt | Data | Id | StateId | StateName | InvocationData | Arguments | CreatedAt | ExpireAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Scheduled | Retry attempt 1 of 10: Could not resolve assembly 'MyCompany.GVA.Api'. | 2024-03-19 11:48:11.953 | {"EnqueueAt":"1710848915953","ScheduledAt":"1710848891953"} | 1 | 7 | Scheduled | {"t":"MyCompany.GVA.Api.BatchJobs.ComplianceRequirementsBatchJob, MyCompany.GVA.Api","m":"InitializeGVABatchJobAsync","p":["MyCompany.GVA.Args.BatchJob.ComplianceRequirementsBatchJobArgs, MyCompany.GVA.Args"]} | ["{}"] | 2024-03-19 11:48:11.853 | null |
| 5 | 1 | Scheduled | Retry attempt 2 of 10: Could not resolve assembly 'MyCompany.GVA.Api'. | 2024-03-19 11:48:35.353 | {"EnqueueAt":"1710848947353","ScheduledAt":"1710848915353"} | 1 | 7 | Scheduled | {"t":"MyCompany.GVA.Api.BatchJobs.ComplianceRequirementsBatchJob, MyCompany.GVA.Api","m":"InitializeGVABatchJobAsync","p":["MyCompany.GVA.Args.BatchJob.ComplianceRequirementsBatchJobArgs, MyCompany.GVA.Args"]} | ["{}"] | 2024-03-19 11:48:11.853 | null |

In addition, `MyCompany.GVA.Api.exe` and `MyCompany.GVA.Api.dll` are both in the same folder. Therefore, the error looks like complete nonsense to me, even like a lie. But it still needs to be resolved someway.

It shows that my my Hangfire application cannot find itself. Why? How can an application possibly have issues finding itself? And how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you setup your hangfire ?  Does this happen when you app is not self-contained ?